# python ctypes, trying to find library names

Tags: python, c, ctypes, shared-objects

I want to use C-functions in my python program and the obvious way is to implement the libraries with "ctypes".

But there is a problem. In C I include different header files that the linker will link with the right libraries. But I only know the name of the header files, but for python I need to know the name of the library files, like "libxyz.so".

So how do I get the linker or whoever to tell me which libraries are used for the different header files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes` dynamically loads the shared object or the DLL, so you need some how the shared object name. You may have a look at [`ctypes.util.find_library(name)`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.util.find_library). For example:

```
>>> from ctypes.util import find_library
>>> 
>>> find_library('pthread')
'libpthread.so.0'
>>> 
>>> find_library('ssl')
'libssl.so.0.9.8'
>>> 
>>> find_library('png')
'libpng12.so.0'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP means with respect to the linker automatically linking libraries based on the header. For MSVC that's [`#pragma comment(lib, "...")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I don't think gcc has an equivalent directive.

Comment: @eryksun mostly the libraries are not specified in the header, the compiler will not then link to the library, these properly some commonly used libraries per-defined in the linker option, e.g `user32.lib`, which he might think the compiler is automatically linking agents.

Comment: thanks. For your examples i get the same returnvalues, but for something like "signal"(signal.h) or "unistd"(unistd.h) i get nothing.

gcc somehow knows how to find the library which includes the funktions from for example signal.h. That's what i meant by automatically knowing the library.

Comment: @user3441497 The functions that are defined in `signal.h`,  `unistd.h` and a lot other are all implemented in a single library `libc`, `find_library('c')`.

Comment: Okay. And what about things like "sys/io.h" ?

Comment: @user3441497 same library :), `libc`, `sys/io.h` has only two functions `ioperm` and `iopl` and the rest are static inlined functions and can't access using ctypes.